# Unable to format, 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Tags: hardware-failure, usb-storage, diskpart

I've just bought a USB drive, however I had some problems with it as soon as I started using it.

At first all of a sudden Windows would just lose the "communication" with it, stopping any task it was doing (copy/paste). Today, as soon as plugged it, Windows just said the device needed to be formatted so I decided to use `DISKPART` to try to solve the problem and here's what I get:

```
>DISKPART> select volume 1

Volume 1 is the selected volume.

>DISKPART> clean

DiskPart has encountered an error: The system cannot find the file specified.
See the System Event Log for more information.

>DISKPART> detail disk

General UDisk USB Device
Disk ID: 00000000
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

 Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 1                             Removable     0 B   Unusable
```

And since I couldn't get past the `clean` command, is there a solution for me?

Comment: Send it back...

Comment: Looks like it is bricked!...

Comment: bricked, what's that?

Comment: bricked. colloquial - as much use as a brick.

Comment: Is it a Flash drive? Could be a fake; lots of those out there unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah it's a Flash drive... but i could use it for sometime before it went completely useless but i guess there's no solution then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harddrives actually have suprisingly high failure rate. Why is beyond me, as I rarely open them for other reason than scavenging fridge magnets, but on the bright side, the manufacturers normally replace early failing harddrives without much trouble, as it's expected that a certain percentage of them will fail despite being new.

Why am I mentioning this? Because the fact that the drive used to work, but now raises all of the red flags in your diagnostic tells me this is one of the failing ones. I would suggest check the RMA-routines for the manufacturer or the reseller, as this to me seems like a straightforward warranty issue.

On a related note: Many drives that are considered "high grade" versions of regular drives are often just those regular drives with some extra time spent stress-testing them to weed out the ones that would fail early on.

Comment: Well, i'll see to it. It's a pity not being able to resolve it through the PC but at least i got some info but thanks anyway.